# How can I prevent Outlook 2010 from becoming the default mail client

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2010, file-association

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, Outlook 2010 32-bit and Thunderbird.

Thunderbird is my default mail client, but occasionally I have to run Outlook. Whenever I do that, the next time I start Thunderbird, it asks me whether it should become the default mail client again.

In Outlook I have unticked the "default program" option.

Any ideas what is causing this? How can I force Outlook to leave my preference unchanged?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Windows 7:

Go to Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs and then choose your preference. You may set Thunderbird as the default mail application.

Comment: Thunderbird is the default application there for .eml, .wdseml files, for the MAILTO protocol, and for MAPI Send mail commands (everything listed). Looking at Outlook from that default programs applet, it is _not_ selected for .eml, MAILTO, and MAPI. Still doesn't help. The next time I run Outlook, followed by running Thunderbird, the latter asks me to set it as a default. Just noticed, though, that those default program settings appear unchanged. So maybe this is just a bug in Thunderbird?

Comment: there is also another option called __default programs__ just next to the **unset** box in outlook express(tools->options->otherTab).you may try that!

Comment: Hi Dipesh, thanks for the answers. But I'm using Outlook, not Outlook Express.